# Trying to remove or override inline style of a div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to update the following html

```
<div class="row scheduled-event event-collapsed event-hidden" data-date="2019-01-29" data-location="" style="display: none;">
```

to

```
<div class="row scheduled-event event-collapsed event-visible" data-date="2019-01-29" data-location="">
```

for these i came up with the following jQuery, but I can't remove/update the style attribute

```
//replace hidden


$('div.row').filter(function(){
          var e = $(this).data('date');
          return e == '2019-01-29';
        }).removeClass( "event-hidden" ).addClass( "event-visible" );

//remove attr style or update to display: block !important
        $('div.row').filter(function(){
          var e = $(this).data('date');
          return e == '2019-01-29';
        }).removeAttr('style');
```

I am able to replace hidden for visible, but the style stills exists

Any suggestions??

Comment: why add both a class and an inline style?  Also, why have a class for being visible?  Just have one class for hidden and then you just need to toggle that class rather than adding a cl;ass and removing another one

Comment: @Pete, well I am altering a WP plugin to a specific requirement. I think the style is added later in the process, so I think i need the removeAttr when the page is loaded

Comment: You would need to create a [mcve] showing your problem as with the code you have provided, I do not see why your attribute wouldn't be removed

Comment: I checked your code and it is working fine on my side. It may be due to some js breaks.